# How would I add a hidden field to product page

Tags: product, configurable-product, product-view

I need to add a hidden field to my product page after creating a second attribute, the hidden field should have a value of "not" and a check box for yes thus leaving me with a configurable product with two attributes.

Comment: If you still need this, please update the question with additional information on what you are trying to achieve, the question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if this applies to all configurables, copy *`catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`* to your custom theme and add the hidden input there.

But really, what the hell are you trying to?? :-D

Comment: I have a fabric site if you look at this product

Comment: http://homefabricsandtrims.com/window-panels-1/merano-drapery.html 
I need the customer to be able to check the box sample and add to cart without having to pick a color therefore checking out from the website with a sample of that product then I will ship them a sample for approval it's driving me nuts!

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to a much better way of doing it?

Comment: If the samples don't need to be a certain color, why not make "sample" an option for the configurable attribute?

Comment: selecting one of the color as default while loading using javascript is an another possiblity. @benmarks suggestion is also good and adding a hidden field is also another method. if you dont want to do further editing, then use javascript and set a color as default. this may solve your problem I think

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me, I do need the sample to be a certain color (whatever the customer requests) 
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated thanks a lot for even replying!